# How do I use this code?

Tags: javascript

I have this code, but I don't know how to wrap it in Drupal.

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {

  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }

});
```

I've already activated the .js file and added the detail in .info, I can see it from the firebug that is OK, but from the Firebug console I can see that I have syntax errors.

From Drupal website I can see this example.

```js
(function ($) { // Here code javascript })(jQuery);
```

Can someone show me how the code above should look like into Drupal? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.yourCustomName = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $(document, context).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 100) {
          $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
        }
      });

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Be sure to [read the docs](http://drupal.org/node/171213#behaviors).

Comment: You should always use jQuery once to avoid re-attaching behavior to the same element. And yes, something behaviors are attached multiple time using the root element (ie. document) as context.
See https://coderwall.com/p/kd-4cg for a bit more information on JavaScript in Drupal 7.

Comment: @PierreBuyle *always* is a bit strong word here. In this case, only on first page load document should be in context. But good hint anyway :)

Comment: There is no guarantee that only the page load will apply the behaviors to a context containing the document element. So you can't assume it will never happen. Unless you are ready to review all JavaScript files from all the added modules.